# .populate doesn't work with mongoose 5.2

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-populate

In my mongoose I have a parent and a child entry. The relationship between the two is defined through the standard mongoose ref keyword:

```
const childSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  ...
   theParent: { ref: "TheParentCollection" }
})
```

In my JavaScript application I'm selecting the child entry while trying to populate the parent in one statement:

```
Child.find({}).populate('theParent')
```

Everything works fine with mongoose 5.1. the parent gets populated to a full object correctly.
However, when I upgrade to mongoose 5.2 - the parent ends up being null.

In the my mongodb debug log I'm seeing the queries generated behind the scenes are exactly the same:

```
thechildcollection.find({}, { fields: {} })
theparentcollection.find({ _id: { '$in': [ 'BinData(4, "+ulLF+9kT22qGZf9Z9p0Ew==")' ] } }, { fields: {} })
```

I've debugged it enough to verify that the generated query retrieves the parent object correctly, it's just that mongoose dooes not map the result correctly.
I've tried both with mongo 4.0 and 3.6 and same behavior. It seems to be all about mongoose 5.2.

Comment: How your collection looks like? and what is `BInData` here?

Comment: Updated the question with new findings. Seems like it all comes down to the mongoose version.

Comment: yes mongoose 5.x works with mongodb 3.6 and above... If you have 3.6 then is should works... I think you should now try to use `$lookup` aggregation  and forgot about populate methods